# Hive+pyspark. Py4JJavaError: NoClassDefFoundError: /Logging$class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I try use hive with my pyspark. I follow this example: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html. It is a base example hive in pyspark. So, my code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import expanduser, join, abspath
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # warehouse_location points to the default location for managed databases and tables
    warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
    spark.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
    spark.sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()
    spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM src").show()
    sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT key, value FROM src WHERE key < 10 ORDER BY key")
    stringsDS = sqlDF.rdd.map(lambda row: "Key: %d, Value: %s" % (row.key, row.value))
    for record in stringsDS.collect():
        print(record)
    Record = Row("key", "value")
    recordsDF = spark.createDataFrame([Record(i, "val_" + str(i)) for i in range(1, 101)])
    recordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("records")
    spark.sql("SELECT * FROM records r JOIN src s ON r.key = s.key").show()
    spark.stop()
```

After run i get the error:
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.sql.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class`
The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-c54a2a0ac76b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA/Desktop/test_spark_5.py', wdir='C:/Users/SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA/Desktop/test_spark_5.py", line 31, in <module>
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Desktop\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Desktop\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Desktop\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\SUBD-PodpruzhnikovIA\Desktop\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.sql.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.<init>(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$build$2(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
24 more
```

I use Spark 2.4.0, pyspark 2.4.0, java 8, python 3.6. master=local. Any ideas? I would really appreciate)

UPD: if use spark 2.3.2 (local), pyspark 2.3.2, then first part of code work normal, so there is CREATE TABLE, show it and show COUNT. After that it fail with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'. It is a old error, it fixed in older versions spark.

UPD2: i add the code, which can ran on yarn for Jacek Laskowski

```
from os.path import expanduser, join, abspath
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import Row
import os
from operator import add
from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway
os.environ["HADOOP_USER_NAME"] = "administrator"
SparkContext._gateway=launch_gateway()
SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]='/opt/pypy3.6-v7.1.1-linux64/bin/ipython3'
conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.setAppName('PythonSparkintegrationexampleYARN')
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "16G")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8032")
conf.set("spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems", "hdfs://hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8020")
conf.set("spark.yarn.stagingDir", "hdfs://hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8020/user/administrator/stagingDir")
conf.set("spark.executor.userClassPathFirst", "true")
conf.set("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst", "true")
conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
conf.set("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs://hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8020/user/spark/spark2ApplicationHistory")
conf.set("spark.history.fs.logDirectory", "hdfs://hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8020/user/spark/spark2ApplicationHistory")
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
conf.set("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "600")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "60000")
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "400")
conf.set("spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME", "administrator")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
file=sc.textFile(HDFS_URI+curr_file)
words = file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
dataColl = words.countByValue()
for word, count in dataColl.items():
    print("{} : {} ".format(word, count ))
sc.stop()
```

if i try to use hive, i add:

```
warehouse_location= abspath('hdfs://hadoop-manager1.some-site.ru:8020/user/hive/warehouse')
ss=SparkSession(sc).builder.appName('SparkSession_Hive_reader_2')\
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location)\
.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
ss.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src(key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
ss.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'C:/Spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12-2/examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
ss.sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()
```

With the last add i have the following error:

````
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6c223a8545bf> in <module>
----> 1 ss.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src(key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
      2 ss.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'C:/Spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12-2/examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
      3 
      4 # Queries are expressed in HiveQL
      5 ss.sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    768         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    769         """
--> 770         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    771 
    772     @since(2.0)

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: "Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;\n'CreateTable `src`, Ignore\n" ```
````

Comment: How do you run the app? Why Spark 2.4.0 not the latest 2.4.7 or even 3.0.2?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski , I use the spark version 2.4.0 on my computer, because I need to connect to yarn, which has version 2.4.0. With other versions of spark on my computer, I can't connect to the server. I run local and yarn jobs sucssesful, when I have spark 2.4.0. My main task is to connect to the hive tables and perform their processing on yarn. But I failed. I started looking for the cause of the problem and got to the point where the basic example with hive doesn't run.

Comment: Can you show how you run the app? You can use any Spark version on any YARN cluster BTW.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I add info in question's body. Also, i use scala 2.12, python 3.6.12, hadoop 2.6, write HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, SCALA_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

Comment: It's still unclear how you submit the pyspark app for execution? Do you use `spark-submit` at all? If not, why?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, If I use spark-submit, I don't know it myself. I use spyder and jupyterlab and the run button.